# MYSQL/PHP: Select part of word OR exact match

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tried looking for an answer for my question. If a similar question have been asked, please point me to that page.

I have a form where the user types search words in one or multiple text fields.

Then passed to SQL statment:

```
WHERE st.Description LIKE '%$Description%'
AND st.Number LIKE '%$Number%'
AND st.Color LIKE '%$Color%'
```

This will return any matches where the word **contains** the user input.

Is there any way, that if the user uses quotations (like "search word") that it will search for exact match?

What's best practice?

Comment: You can handle this logic in the query itself, or better yet handle it in the PHP code.  If the search string contains quotes, then use a different `LIKE` expression without wildcards `%`.

Comment: Do you mean loop through the input fileds and use and if statement if it contains quotes? and if so put the expression into php variables?

Comment: I mean check the input in your PHP code, and handle quotes appropriately.  Basically, you want `LIKE 'search string'` if it has quotes, but `LIKE '%search string%'` if it doesn't have quotes.

Comment: Yes, how can PHP detect if a word/words is surrounded by quotes? EDIT: found preg_match('/^(["\']).*\1$/m', $string);

Comment: Use '%".$Description."%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it form the php code, before excuting the query

Let's assume the serch word is in a variable called `$keyword`

```
<?php 
if(substr($keyword, 0, 1) == '"' && substr($keyword, -1, 1) ==='"'){
    $search = ' = ' . substr($keyword, 1, -1);
}else{
    $search = ' LIKE ' . '%' . $keyword . '%';
}
```

Then use the `$search` variable in your query

```
<?php
  $sql = ... WHERE st.Description $search and  st.Number $search and  st.Color $search
```

Dont forget to use prepared statements to prevent `SQL injections`

And for performance matters, if you are looking for an exact word, dont use `LIKE` keyword, use `=` comparison symbol

Comment: I trying to use this, but also include the 'LIKE' expression as $search= 'LIKE %' . $searchOpts['Description'] . '%'; but it wont work.

Comment: I added this to the `$search` variable

Comment: Also, do you really have to use `AND` in your sql queries, I guess you mean `OR`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way, that if the user uses quotations (like "search word") that it will search for exact match?

If you remove the quotes that's exactly what it does search for: `WHERE st.Description LIKE '%search word%'`. The implies that you think you are currently searching for the presence of the words out of order when multiple words are supplied as search terms. This is not the case. Presumable given a phrase with multiple words you want to search for all of the words:

```
WHERE st.Description LIKE '%search%'
AND st.Description LIKE '%word%'
```

> What's best practice?

A *very* long way from what you are currently doing: use fulltext indexing or build your own keyword search.